# Mass update simple product "status" via MySQL query

Tags: mysql, magento, e-commerce

I just imported over 12k products to my Magento catalog.

Problem is, the products came with the "Status" field undefined, and I need to seem them to "Enabled" manually if I want to use them in the front-end store. Doing this manually would take hours.

Do you know where this setting is defined in the database? Do you know of a query that would this automatically (I want to set ALL products to "Enabled").

Comment: You can write a small script for that.

Answer (score 20):

```
# First find the ID of the product status attribute in the EAV table:
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 4 AND attribute_code = 'status'

# Then use that status attribute ID ($id) while querying the product entity table:
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value = 1 WHERE attribute_id = $id
```

- 1 - enabled
- 2 - disabled

Comment: Have in mind that different values are stored in different tables. If your value is of type 'varchar' it will be in catalog_product_entity_varchar - you can check this in the eav_attribute table structure. Thanks for this, it helped me out.

Answer (score -8):

Will set *all* rows as enabled

```
UPDATE Catalog SET Status='Enabled'
```

If you want to have it enabled by default you could modify this a little bit.

```
ALTER TABLE `Catalog` CHANGE `Status` `Status` ENUM('','Enabled','Disabled') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Enabled'
```

Comment: which Magento version does this apply to?

Comment: This does not apply to any magento version, it seems.